# Handling viewbox click event in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent, textblock, viewbox

I have a `Viewbox` and a `TextBlock` inside it. But `TextBlock` doesn't occupy whole `Viewbox`. Can I handle an event when user clicks the `Viewbox`, not `TextBlock`?

Just setting `MouseDown` event doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try PreviewMouseDown?

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work either.

Comment: why do you need a viewbox?

Comment: I need to dynamically size text to parent container size

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<Viewbox Width="100">
            <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Width="100" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <TextBox Width="20">sdgdf</TextBox>
            </StackPanel>
</Viewbox>
```

add the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` event to `StackPanel`, set it `Background="Transparent"`. And the code behind:

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("FIRE!");
}
```

Comment: Still nothing. It fires only when I click directly on TextBlock.

Comment: It doesn't if you try to set the viewbox something with size different than the viewbox. the click it's acting only in the child

Comment: Of course it works, but I use `Viewbox` to dynamically resize text to parent container size. With your solution text size will be constant and `StackPanel` will not fit `Viewbox`

Comment: Just dock the `StackPanel` to `ViewBox`, why not?